# Can OKTA create users on external platforms

Tags: okta, okta-api

I have a requirement where an external application user needs to be created through OKTA, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

More detail on your use case would be helpful in providing most appropriate answer.

One case is where users (in Okta's Universal Directory) and external application exist in Okta (as single sign on app). Users can be created in downstream (external) application via provisioning. When user is assigned to application in Okta and provisioning is implemented/enabled for that app that user will be created in the downstream application.

If provisioning is what you are looking for it is recommended that you consider SCIM (System for Cross Domain Identity Management). You can read about SCIM here http://www.simplecloud.info/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_for_Cross-domain_Identity_Management.